# Force Angular 6 to NEVER reuse a component

Tags: jquery, angular, routes, angular-routing

I'm having an issue with Angular 6 when I travel to a list page at least twice.

In this list page I add information to a table

```
<table id="table-products" class="wb-tables table table-striped table-hover" data-wb-tables='{ "ordering" : false }'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
    <td>{{product.id}}</td>
    <td><a routerLink="{{product.routerLink}}">{{product.title}}</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the information is loaded in the backend like so:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getAll().subscribe( (products: IProduct[]) => {
      this.products = products;
      this.products.map(p => p.routerLink = ['../' + p.id]);
    });
  }
```

I also have to invoke some javascript when the component's view is inited

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (wb.isReady) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.wb-tables:not(.wb-tables-inited)').trigger('wb-init.wb-tables');
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

This works well on the first load regardless if I enter url in browser or navigate from a different component. But when I come back to it the second time from normal router link navigation, I'm having an issue where the javascript isn't initializing the data table properly.

It seems like it caches the component? Although the constructor and ngOnInit is invoked on all calls...

I've tried adding a custom reuse strategy but that isn't working...

```
export class ProductsRouteReuseStrategyService implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {}
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle|null { return null; }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Does the routine in your `ngAfterViewInit` depend on your back-end `ngOnInit` work to be done? It's possible that the second time you navigate to the component, your browser is able to load and render it much more quickly which may be exposing an async issue.

Comment: You are right, if I increase the timeout to 100 instead of 0, with 9 items or so it works every time. Is there a way to instead of doing a timeout to have it do it after we are sure there is data? putting it in the subscribe function doesn't work because the view isn't updated then.